# ruby:using regex i want to split sql statements

Tags: ruby, regex, oracle11g, oci8

i'm using ruby and sinatra and oci8 and i want to run an sql file which contain multiple sql statements  but oci8 just can let me execute one statement

```
str="INSERT INTO AA(NAME) VALUES ('asasa')"
@conn1 = OCI8.new(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_SERVER)
@conn1.exec(str)
```

for that i have to split all sql statements by using regex but i had a problem in that,i did'nt find a regex which let me do this. i want to split all statments

example of an sql file ;

```
create table users (name varchar2(20),age int);
begin
insert into users values('amine5',20);
insert into users values('amine5',30);
end;
```

the file can contain all sql statements

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to do this and you should probably just execute the SQL directly without OCI8 for these initial inserts but anyway, a question - will these only be insert statements?

Comment: no i'm dealing with all sql statements,i know that's difficult to do this but i don't know any gem which can read an sql fil and execute it or which can execute many sql statements in the same time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for you if you are only dealing with insert statements.

```
string2.0.0-p353 :001 > string =<<-EOS
2.0.0-p353 :002"> insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');
2.0.0-p353 :003"> begin
2.0.0-p353 :004"> insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');
2.0.0-p353 :005"> insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');
2.0.0-p353 :006"> end;
2.0.0-p353 :007"> insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');
2.0.0-p353 :008"> EOS
 => "insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');\nbegin\ninsert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');\ninsert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');\nend;\ninsert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');\n" 
2.0.0-p353 :012 > string.scan(/insert.+;/i)
 => ["insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');", "insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');", "insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');", "insert into users values('amine5','sdfsdf');"]
```

Rubular permalink: http://rubular.com/r/Ffrd4swl4z

Comment: i'm not only dealing with insert statements,i'm dealing with all sql statements thanks for your response